# how to convert Unicode (utf-8) to hex string in java?

Tags: java, string, unicode, utf-8

how to convert a unicode string in java to hex string.

for example : st = "\u0645"  to st = "%D9%85"

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can afford Guava, go for it and use its [`PercentEscaper`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v16.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/net/PercentEscaper.html) (available as of Guava 15.0).

As nearly always with Guava, well written and performs admirably.

Note that it will not encode ASCII letters or digits (a-z, A-Z, 0-9).

Comment: You're welcome! And don't forget to explore Guava. It is a "gold mine of gems", so to speak ;)